# charset issue when using html5/jquery/php/mysql

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, character-encoding

I have a HTML 5 page with this in the header:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

On the same page I make an Ajax request with Jquery in this way:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "ajax/subscribe.php",
        type: "POST",
        encoding: "UTF-8",
        data: formData,...
```

All works fine, in ajax/subscribe.php I have this header:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

And My MySQL-database had a default charset of utf8_unicode_ci. But... When I process a word like this 'égallement', it is saved in database as 'gallement', the é is stripped. There is also send an email automatically, and in this email the 'é' is replaced by a question mark. Anny suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) JavaScript function before adding it to the query string.

and content type should be as below:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I tried this:

```
var formData = {
        naam: encodeURIComponent($("#inputNaam").val()),
        voornaam: encodeURIComponent($("#inputVoornaam").val())
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/subscribe.php",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        data: formData,...
```

But now the data is saved in db like this:

T%c3%a9%c3%a9%c3%a9st. The é is replaced by %c3%a9%

SOLVED: in the PHP file I have to use urldecode() on each string I get with POST